# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index when i want to use matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

my code for create a plot of the pendulum period vs. length for pendulums with string lengths of 10 cm to 2 m.
anyone could solve this problem?!
i wrote this code but it's not work and has type error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

g = 9.8
L1 = np.arange (10, 201)
print (L1)

for t in range (L1):
    Length = L1/100
    t = (math.sqrt(Length/9.8)) * 2* 3.14
    print (t)
    plt.plot (Length, t)
```

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Comment: `L1` is already a range.  You don't want to call `range(L1)`.

Comment: how can solve this, how fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

g = 9.8
L1 = np.arange (10, 201)

for t in L1:
    Length = L1/100
    a = (np.sqrt(Length/9.8)) * 2* 3.14
    plt.plot (Length, a)
```